# Run an angular function from VBA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vba, excel, web-scraping

I wrote a small VBA macro that fills the form fields on the site. The site is written in Angular. To fill in the fields on this site I use this code:

```vb
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[data-ng-model=""text""]').val('sometext').change();"
```

On the site there is a button to which the event is attached:

```
data-ng-click = "startFunction()"
```

Please tell me if I can programmatically from VBA trigger an event     `data-ng-click = "startFunction()"` without clicking a button on the site?

I tried to do so:

```vb
Call oie.document.parentWindow.execScript("startFunction()")
```

but it did not work. Perhaps somehow you can also run the software Angular function on the site?

Comment: Please share the code you have including URL, check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you finally need to retrieve some data from the website?